# AngularJs, Img, onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I must do a website. On this website when you click on img it adds a text to the div.
It must has directives and controllers i dont have a clue how to do this...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
<title>AngularJS System Zamówień</title>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = new Date();
    $scope.hambureger ={
        nazwa: 'Hambureger',
        cena: '5',
    }
    $scope.crips = {
        nazwa: 'Crips',
        cena: '4',
    }
    $scope.cola = {
        nazwa: 'Coca-Cola',
        cena: '3',
    }
    $scope.show = function() {

   }
   }
   myApp.directive1('myDir1', function () {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<br>{{hamburger.nazwa}}'

    };
});
myApp.directive2('myDir2', function () {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<br>{{frytki.nazwa}}
    };
});
myApp.directive3('myDir3', function () {
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<br>{{cola.nazwa}}'

    };
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="ladne"><center>System zamówień żarcia</center></h1>
<div class="d1" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<img src="styles/img/cola.gif" ng-click=""></img>
<img src="styles/img/fryt.gif" ng-click=""></img>
<img src="styles/img/ham.gif" ng-click=""></img>
<br>
<div class="zam">
Data Zamówienia: {{data |date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
<br>
Twoje zamówienie: //HERE ANGULAR MUST ADD A TEXT
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's really hard for me to do this...
So let's explain one more time:
When u click on img, text is added to div(class="zam"), when you press next img it adds new text in new line. Here are 3 diffrent imgs Crips, Hambureger 'n' cola

Comment: What text you want to add to the div?

Comment: I am not sure if this code runs at all! Does angular module have methods `directive1`, `directive2` or `directive3`?

Comment: So guys, I want to add my template from directive to Div, where's "Twoje zamówienie:". For example when i press img where is cola it add to "Twoje Zamówienie: Directive with template "<br>{{cola.nazwa}}"